# Qt internationalization from native language

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization

I am going to write software in Qt. Its string literals should be written in native (non-English) language and they should support internationalization. The Qt docs advice to use `tr()` function for this http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html

So I try to write:

```
edit->setText(tr("Фильтр"));
```

and and I can see only question marks in running app
I replace it with `QString::fromStdWString`

```
   edit->setText(QString::fromStdWString(L"Фильтр"));
```

and I can see correct text in my language

So the question is: **How should I write non-ASCII strings to be able to correctly display them and translate using Qt Linguist**

PS: I use UTF8 encoding for all source files, compiler is vs2013

PS2: I have found `QTextCodec::setCodecForTr()`  function.. but It was removed from Qt 5.4

Comment: why not use an ascii compatible language for the source?

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Um, I guess because his native language is non-ascii compatible; on one hand, I do really think that the time of "ascii is obligatory" are over (and I'm really happy about that), but on the other hand, it might not be very easy to read code that interleaves English Qt Names with Kyrillic Strings.

Comment: It's not easy to write either. But unfortunately it is not possible to translate terms from specific areas "on the fly", especially if your team mates do not know English))

Comment: and [trUtf8](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject-obsolete.html#trUtf8)?

Comment: trUtf8 was removed as well

Comment: Rem, btw, what's your specific area? I don't speak a word of Russian, but if I try to pronounce *Фильтр*, it sounds like *filterr*, and since I'm in the signal processing business, I'm kind of curious ;)

Comment: My area is CAD for furniture.. it has a lot of terms for wood boards, furniture and production technology

Comment: [C++11 string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). Have you tried `edit->setText(tr(u8"Фильтр"));`?

Comment: As mentioned before I'm using VS2013 compiler which doesn't support this feature

Comment: Does `edit->setText(QString::fromStdWString(tr("Фильтр").toStdWString()));` work? What about : `edit->setText(QString::fromLocal8Bit(tr("Фильтр").toLocal8Bit()));`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best option is to use some kind of Latin1 transliteration inside program source. Then, it's possible to implement both Russian and English versions as normal Qt translations.

BTW. It's possible, with some additional work, to use even plain numbers as translation-placeholders. Just like MFC did.

Answer (score 0):

I found the strange solution for my problem:

By default VS saves files in UTF8 with BOM. In *File -> Advanced save* options I choose to save file in *UTF without BOM* and everything works like a charm:

```
edit->setText(tr("Фильтр"));
```

It looks like a VS compiler bug.. Interestingly MS claims that its compiler support Unicode only for  UTF8 **with BOM** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwy0e8f2.aspx

PS: length of "Фильтр" is 12 bytes, so it is really utf8 string